# installing cisco packet tracer

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

when I try to install Cisco packet tracer like the way the install instructions say

```
sudo apt-get install ./CiscoPacketTracer_xxx_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
```

I get this message why

```
E: Unsupported file /CiscoPacketTracer_820_Ubuntu_64bit.deb given on commandline
```

Comment: What command are you using to install it? Add it to your question.

Comment: the way the instructions say " User@Ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install ./CiscoPacketTracer_xxx_Ubuntu_64bit.deb"

Comment: Maybe you should install with `sudo dpkg -i ./CiscoPacketTracer_xxx_Ubuntu_64bit.deb`. Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this how i sorted it out.

1. Open your terminal.
2. Navigate to the directory where you downloaded the `.deb` package file. You can use the `cd` command to change to the appropriate directory. For example:

   ```shell
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
3. Install the `.deb` package using `dpkg`:

   ```shell
   sudo dpkg -i CiscoPacketTracer_821_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
   ```
4. Replace `CiscoPacketTracer_821_Ubuntu_64bit.deb` with the actual filename of the Packet Tracer `.deb` package you downloaded.
5. If you encounter any dependency issues, you can use the following command to try to fix them:

   ```shell
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
6. You should be able to launch Cisco Packet Tracer from your application menu or by running `packettracer` from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I used

```
sudo dpkg -i ./Cisco_Packet_Tracker_xxx_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
```

It didn't install it but it let me use

```
sudo apt-get install ./CiscoPacketTracer_xxx_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
```

still gave me error but now you can use.

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install ./CiscoPacketTracer_xxx_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
```